# SyncFusion Blazor - Word to PDF

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, syncfusion

I have a Blazor WASM Self Hosted Project and I'm trying to use SyncFusion Blazor to export from Word to PDF.

I already opened a question on their forum but they can`t reproduce the problem that I'm facing. I'm missing something but I don't understand what is it.

https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/184016/download-as-pdf?reply=SDUMVy

I'm putting the link of the question because I don't know what else I can provide. Here is the image of the error:

[image]

I've tried another browser, delete bin/obj and other things but still having the problem on this line:

```
//Converts Word document into PDF document
    Syncfusion.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDocument = render.ConvertToPDF(doc);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does that actually work with WASM? The shown error says "no". Confirmed here: https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/issues/846

Comment: Based on your tip I decided to try another approach. Sended everything to the server and worked there. Now I think it's working the way I expected. Thanks